# How can I attach hardwood backing panels to a frame?

Tags: joinery, hand-tools, boxes

Preface: I only have access to hand tools. I am a novice at design and drawing perspectives, I unfortunately only have technical abilities right now because I've only copied other people's work to learn. This is just a spontaneous Christmas present I would like to tackle and help push my woodworking forward.

Based on : https://www.simplyeasydiy.com/2014/12/diy-roll-around-laundry-hamper-with_10.html

I will build 4 frames utilizing 1x3s and dowels, I will attach the backing in question here, then attach those 4 frames using dowels again. From there I will laminate a bottom, glue it to the square frame previously built, add some nails and caster wheels, then work on the lid and hinge. I believe this to be solid for simplicity.

Please understand I am trying to keep it as basic as possible. I just want it all to function first and foremost. I am not going for the world's strongest hamper.

My question is: how can I go about adding some nice contrast wood backing pieces to the 4 frames to set it apart visually, rather than a bunch of Home Depot pine? Would glue suffice here, possibly with a few more dowels? Although that would be a ridiculous amount of dowels at that point, I'm not sure I want the back panels to show their joinery, if I have to that's fine of course.

Thank you for your time!

[image: Drawing]

Comment: Before anything else realise you're essentially making a box. What else are boxes? Cabinets. Blanket cases. Chests. The approximately gazillion resources online about building these will give you plenty of ideas or actual plans you can steal/modify, so you don't have to try to design this from first principles. It'll also tend to show you what works and, of great help for future projects, why..... for example along the way you should find out why you can't make a 'backing sheet' from solid wood (even if you were in a position too make this panel, which you don't currently have the tools for).

Comment: I feel like there are differences in structural integrity and approach when the box is 90% of boxes, on their side. Solid wood panels. I imagine you can't make it from solid wood because of warping. Doesn't paneling solve that?

Comment: I will just buy one at this rate, it's apparently too difficult to do with hand tools, plus there are plenty of sources to copy on the internet if I wanted to, rather than requesting help here developing my own.

Comment: Look at recycling bins, laundry boxes, laundry hampers, there should be something of similar shape to this (and BTW I can predict most you'll find will be made from plywood or maybe MDF!) *"Doesn't paneling solve that?"* Not sure what you mean by this. If you mean a panel made from multiple boards glued together versus a single very wide board they basically act the same as far as expansion and contraction across their width goes (also why roughly equal allowance must be made for movement in tabletops perhaps glued up from 3 boards and in countertops made from all those narrow strips).

Comment: Just seems crazy to me that nothing can be made without plywood or MDF anymore even though woodworking is millennia old. I guess nobody used hampers until plywood came around, I am just not a big fan of plywood for whatever reason, namely because I like to chisel.

Comment: This type of thing isn't at all too difficult to do with hand tools! It may be beyond the tools you have at the moment to do *a specific type* of box, but simple boxes are one of the classic things to begin with when learning precisely because they're not too difficult. And these days with multiple materials to pick from it's easier than ever to make boxes because we have access to manmade board materials that are dimensionally stable. If this were me I'd make it from decent ply, butt jointed together with glue and dowels, drill ventilation holes and after some careful sanding paint it.

Comment: I understand about plywood but does being dimensionally stable versus the (idea) purity of hardwood really matter when people throw things out after a few years these days? My grandma has gigantic hardwood cabinets from decades ago, they haven't degraded at all, no plywood in sight. I didn't understand the rampant use of plywood until I began getting away from "skill developing" tutorials. Now I can't find very many projects without plywood. I was going to just cut tons of dovetails but I can't find solid panels that big anyway, dovetailing a frame doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: *"Just seems crazy to me that nothing can be made without plywood or MDF anymore even though woodworking is millennia old. I guess nobody used hampers "* Manmade board materials are used because they're suitable, they solve various problems, and they make construction so much faster (ergo cheaper). All solid reasons. But this sort of thing is **completely** doable entirely from solid wood, IF the right tools are available for the necessary construction details that either sidestep wood movement (q.v. shiplap or T&G) or allow for it (q.v. floating panels {as in Shaker doors}).

Comment: I have a large variety of hand tools, too many to list here, auxiliaries at least, and marking/measuring tools, I have plenty of chisels, gouges, saws and planes which make up most of my gear. I do not have a plow plane because it's always out of stock, the only specialty plane I have is a Veritas router plane. I feel like a plow plane would come in handy for processing this idea if I had one.

Comment: If you want to get input on this SE is not the place for it, because it's set up to provide (as much as poss) canonical Answers to specific Questions. I'd suggest asking in a regular forum environment, where the back-and-forth you need to get into is what they're set up for. Set out your question like this: *I want to build the following for my grandma, the dimensions are XXXX and I want to make it from solid wood; with limited tools at my disposal can you help me come up with a workable design?*

Comment: Thanks for not being a jerk and providing some understanding from where I am coming from. Besides just not having space for power equipment I simply enjoy chiseling and the like. I am obviously ew to this forum, it came up as I searched. I will have to be more precise in the future, perhaps I am not ready for it yet as I cannot provide specific thoughts and questions well enough. Regards.

Comment: *"I have a large variety of hand tools, too many to list here"* Hang on a second, that's not what you said earlier!

Comment: 90% of the things I've observed have been built with, well, blades: planes, chisels, knives, axes... I have a lot of auxiliary things, but the bread and butter is all in hand tools, I don't have a table saw, band saw (yet, it's the only thing on my list for now), miter saw, shaper, etc... I have lots of gear to supplement the bread and butter hand tools I have, but none of it is power, if that makes sense... I use hand tools, of course I've accumulated a lot of things! I've just never strayed from tutorials and practice yet so this step is proving difficult for me. Conceptualizing

Comment: Voting to close just because this question is all over the place. I can't tell if you're asking how to physically attach wood panels, or if it's a design question, or what. The fact that there's a wide-ranging conversation in comments also suggests that the question needs more focus. But welcome to Woodworking, in any case. I'll be happy to reverse my vote if you'll edit it to be more focused on a specific question.

Comment: Restating @graphus, google “frame and panel”. That’ll show you a few methods to get solid wood into a frame, and some don’t require power tools.